# Netflix dgs springboot UI http://localhost:8080/graphiql not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, netflix-dgs

1. Trying to implement graphql api by netflix-dgs.
2. Getting resource not found error.
3. Sharing below the code snippet

**Getting the below error**

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jan 08 14:43:37 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource graphiql.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource graphiql.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
```

**Dependencies inside pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hpe.gravity</groupId>
    <artifactId>aiops.graphql.ervice.java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aiops.graphql.ervice.java</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
                <artifactId>graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies</artifactId>
                <!-- The DGS BOM/platform dependency. This is the only place you set version of DGS -->
                <version>4.9.16</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>arangodb-spring-data</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1-snapshot</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**schema.graphqls under resources**

```
type Query {
    shows(titleFilter: String): [Show]
}

type Show {
    title: String
    releaseYear: Int
}
```

**Datafetcher**

```
import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.DgsComponent;
import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.DgsQuery;
import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.InputArgument;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@DgsComponent
public class DeviceDataFetcherImpl {

    private final List<Show> shows = List.of(
            new Show("Stranger Things", 2016),
            new Show("Ozark", 2017),
            new Show("The Crown", 2016),
            new Show("Dead to Me", 2019),
            new Show("Orange is the New Black", 2013)
    );

    @DgsQuery
    public List<Show> shows(@InputArgument String titleFilter) {
        if(titleFilter == null) {
            return shows;
        }

        return shows.stream().filter(s -> s.getTitle().contains(titleFilter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Tried added below properties in application properties**

```
dgs.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true
dgs.graphql.graphiql.path=/graphiql
dgs.graphql.path=/graphql
```

*cannot find why  dispatcher servlet is not able to load dgs component, not able to find what i am missing here*

Answer (score 0):

With Springboot version > 3.0 graphql platform dependency version above 6 is required.

It worked with below dependency

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
                <artifactId>graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies</artifactId>
                <!-- The DGS BOM/platform dependency. This is the only place you set version of DGS -->
                <version>8.2.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing version to 8.2.0 resolved the issue. thanks @Yash

Comment: This can be commented because it is not a solution